# How to fetch 20 million record/document in mongodb?

Tags: java, mongodb, out-of-memory, mongodb-query

I have collection with 20 million records/documents. I want to fetch all the records in one call by using simple collection.find() method in Java.

I am not able to fetch it because Java is throwing OutOfMemory exception. I increased the heap size in eclipse.ini as 2048m but it didn’t help.

Comment: Hm, ever thought of reading [ESR's "How To Ask Questions The Smart Way"](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)? Your question is lacking all important information. Please elaborate according to the essay.

Comment: Do you want the whole document to be fetched or just few fields of a document?

Comment: LalitAgarwal  - I want to fetch the whole document.

Comment: Most readers will not know what "crore" is. Say 20 million instead of 2 crore.

Comment: Possible hints here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219234/mongodb-using-much-memory  I believe the 32 bit driver is limited to 2GB